# Is there a way to overwrite wx.EditableListBox edit button action?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to implement a version of `wx.avd.EditableListBox` in which items edition is done with a DirDialog (in order to manage a list of pathes). Here is what I've done so far. I'm note sure it's the cleanest way to go, tbh. It almost works, but when a directory is selected and the dialog closes, the item in the list is still editable as a string. How could I block item edition from `EditableListBox`?

EDIT: some screenshot explaining the issue
RE-EDIT : found out what's the problem. It's the call to `event.Skip()`. Removing it solves this issue.

Clicking on this button:

[image]

makes apprear a dir chooser (since it's what my code is intended to do):

[image]

But after selecting a directory, the item in the list is in edit mode as a string, like in the EditableListBox:

[image]

What I would like to do is avoid this and have it back to regular state, with the path that was selected in the Dir Dialog:

[image]

```
import wx, wx.adv
import wx.lib.inspection

class EditableDirBox(wx.adv.EditableListBox):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.OnSelectLine)
        self.SetStrings([".", ".."])
        self.GetEditButton().Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonEdit)
        self.selectedIndex=0
        
    def OnButtonEdit(self, event) :
        if self.selectedIndex != -1:
            lines = self.GetStrings()
            path = lines[self.selectedIndex]
            dialog = wx.DirDialog (None, "Choose input directory", "",
                                   wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST)

            if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                dirname = dialog.GetPath()
                lines[self.selectedIndex] = dirname
                self.SetStrings(lines)
        event.Skip()

    def OnSelectLine(self, event) :
        lines=self.GetStrings()
        index = lines.index(event.GetText())
        self.selectedIndex = index
        print()
        event.Skip()


app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World", size=(500,500))
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
panel.SetSizer(sizer)

widget = EditableDirBox(panel)
sizer.Add(widget, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: why do you want to stop editing in the editlistbox?

Comment: Do you mean `event.Skip()`? Because I want to replace EditableListBox's edition with my own.

Comment: no I mean why do you want to stop editing? This is your question, right? The purpose of EditableListBox is to allow editing the items in the list. Am I missing something?

Comment: What I want is to replace the default edit method with a DirDialog, so that when the user clicks on the Edit button, he can select a directory, and the path is inserted in the selected item.
That's what my code does, but the default edit (the textctrl becoming editable) is still on. So my question is: how to disable this standard textctrl editing, so that only the DirDialog is active?

Comment: let me get this straight - you want to perform this operation only once, right? You get dirctrl, choose the directory, and then the button click does not do anything? Or you want something else? If you do - maybe the screenshot would help

Comment: I updated the question to add some screenshot, hope I clarified.

Comment: you can try to do `GetListCtrl().ReadOnly()`.

Comment: In my version of wxPython, there is no `ReadOnly()` in `ListCtrl`.

Comment: try `Disable()`

Comment: This methode doesn't exist either. But I figured it out, it was `event.Skip()` (which proves that I didn't understand quite well what it does...)

Comment: it probably should have been `Enable( false )`. `event.Skip()` lets the default processing work. Without it only you handler is executed, which is what you want 99% of the time with wxCommandEvent.

Comment: Which element shoud I `Enable( False )`? I tried on the `ListCtrl`, but then the different list items can't be selected anymore, which means they can't be edited using the `DirDialog`.